# How to create a directory/file on the disk on runtime

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, file, sockets, io

I Was trying to run this piece of code to generate a directory and a file inside it, the thing is that both the of them won't get created until the program is terminated.

What can i do to create them while the program is still running?

```
def makeDirectory(dirRoot, path, fileName, fromaddr):
  try:
    os.mkdir(dirRoot, 0o0755)
  except OSError as e:
    print(e)

  try:
     os.mkdir(path, 0o0755)
  except OSError as e:
     print(e)

  path = os.path.abspath(path + '/')
  completeName = os.path.join(path, 'foo.txt')
  cnt = open(completeName, 'a')
  cnt.close()
```

Comment: Does the program currently end after you call `makeDirectory`?

Comment: No it does not because i'm using it in a loop 'while True'  and it is responsible for accepting connections from clients